# Minimax tree algorithm implementation

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence

I really don't know how to implement the code to the tree I'm giving and I'm having much trouble doing it.

The homework: Implement a minimax algorithm in python.
 Run your implementation on the following graph and print the final value.

The leaves I have are: `{3, 12, 8} {2, 4, 6} {14, 5, 2}`

```py
import math 

def minimax (curDepth, nodeIndex, 
             maxTurn, scores,  
             targetDepth): 

    # base case : targetDepth reached 
    if (curDepth == targetDepth):  
        return scores[nodeIndex] 

    if (maxTurn): 
        return max(minimax(curDepth + 1, nodeIndex * 2,  
                    False, scores, targetDepth),  
                   minimax(curDepth + 1, nodeIndex * 2 + 1,  
                    False, scores, targetDepth)) 

    else: 
        return min(minimax(curDepth + 1, nodeIndex * 2,  
                     True, scores, targetDepth),  
                   minimax(curDepth + 1, nodeIndex * 2 + 1,  
                     True, scores, targetDepth)) 

# Driver code 
scores = [3, 5, 2, 9, 12, 5, 23, 23] 

treeDepth = math.log(len(scores), 2) 

print("The optimal value is : ", end = "") 
print(minimax(0, 0, True, scores, treeDepth))
```

Comment: The code running on these leafs: {3, 5} {9, 12}

Comment: running your code, i'm getting an indentation error

Comment: The code is written on pycharm
It works but I can't edit it to work on another tree

Comment: I don't know how to edit properly on this site, but I've edited the code again

Comment: Your code runs Ok. The output I got is `12`. What exactly is the problem you are facing? Do you want some help with the algorithm or the code?

Comment: The code runs on these leaves: {3, 5} {2, 9}
I want it to run on these leaves: {3, 12, 8} {2, 4, 6} {14, 5, 2}

Comment: Is there any help I can get?